# Unexpected value in textbox when using radio buttons as well as checkboxes (in jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following jQuery which adds checkbox/radio value to a textbox, however, when the radio value is clicked it seems to be replacing the current value rather than adding to it. It also seems to be adding an extra 1, as 0.07 will appear as 1.07 (for example). What's going on here?

```
jQuery(function($) {
  $('input[name="percentdiscount"]').on('change', function() {
    applyDiscount();
  });

  $('input[type=checkbox]').click(function() {
    let sum = 0;        
    $('input[type=checkbox]:checked').each(function() {
      sum += parseFloat($(this).val());
    });
    $('#sum').val(sum.toFixed(2)).data('total', sum);
    applyDiscount();
  });

  $('input[type=radio]').click(function() {
    let sum = 0;        
    $('input[type=radio]:checked').each(function() {
      sum += parseFloat($(this).val());
    });
    $('#sum').val(sum.toFixed(2)).data('total', sum);
    applyDiscount();
  });

  function applyDiscount() {
    var pc = parseFloat($('input[name="percentdiscount"]:checked').val());
    $('#sum').val(function() {
      return ($(this).data('total') * pc).toFixed(2);
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: Can you add your html

Answer (score 0):

As I am not having idea about your HTML structure, but I think you are making mistake here.

```
// var pc = parseFloat($('input[name="percentdiscount"]:checked').val());
var pc = parseFloat($('input[name="percentdiscount"]').val());
```